# Is the [ecmascript] tag needed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I think this tag should be made synonym with [javascript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript). It currently [has only 6 questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript), 4 of which are JavaScript. One is tagged instead [cold-fusion](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cold-fusion) and another [.net](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.net). It has 0 followers. I'm just concerned it doesn't really serve any useful purpose.

From the ECMAScript [page on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript):

> ECMAScript is the scripting language standardized by Ecma International in the ECMA-262 specification and ISO/IEC 16262. The language is widely used for client-side scripting on the web, in the form of several well-known implementations such as JavaScript, JScript and ActionScript.

There are already [actionscript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/actionscript) and [actionscript-3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/actionscript-3) tags. There is not a [jscript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jscript) tag, but quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript) again:

> JScript is Microsoft's dialect of the ECMAScript standard that is used in Microsoft's Internet Explorer. JScript is implemented as an Active Scripting engine.

And:

> As explained by JavaScript guru Douglas Crockford in his talk titled The JavaScript Programming Language on YUI Theater,
>
> *"Microsoft did not want to deal with Sun about the trademark issue,
>   and so they called their implementation JScript. A lot of people think
>   that JScript and JavaScript are different but similar languages.
>   That's not the case. They are just different names for the same
>   language, and the reason the names are different was to get around
>   trademark issues."*

Thoughts? I don't have a horse in the race one way or another, it just seems the tag is not very useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lately, the term ECMAScript has been becoming relevant again, as ECMAScript 6 is the name for a proposed major overhaul of the language.  That said, the term is only meaningful if the tag has a version number, such as [ecmascript-6](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6).

[ecmascript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript), on its own, means pretty much the same thing as [javascript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript) for all practical purposes.

Let's retag each [ecmascript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript) question as appropriate: change it to a tag with a language version if such precision is needed (unlikely, since the language hasn't evolved much prior to ECMAScript 6), or untag it if just [javascript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript) is descriptive enough.

Comment: That sounds like a plan, I'll work on this. Does anything need to be done to the ECMAScript tag itself once it is removed/changed to versioned tag? Will it just disappear once it is no longer used?

Comment: I removed ECMAScript from 4 unrelated/JavaScript questions, and updated 2 related ECMAScript-6 with a new tag. I added a description for it also which is pending approval.